# Calculate date overlap in months

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula

Need a bit of help, if you'd be so kind.

In MS Excel, I'm trying to work out the number of months that a student attends university based off of the academic year.

For instance, a student enrolls & finishes university on the following dates:

- 23/06/2018 - 23/06/2020

and there are multiple academic years which the student attends:

- 01/08/2017 - 31/07/2018
- 01/08/2018 - 31/07/2019
- 01/08/2018 - 31/07/2020

I want to calculate how many months the student attends in each academic year:

- 01/08/2017 - 31/07/2018 (1 month)
- 01/08/2018 - 31/07/2019 (12 months)
- 01/08/2018 - 31/07/2020 (11 months)

I've managed to calculate the days using this function:

```
=MAX(MIN(term_end_date, student_,end_date) - MAX(term_start_date, student_start_date)+1,0)
```

But, I need months, if possible.

Appreciate the help in advance.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a visual presentation of how your data looks like and how/where your expected results go?

Comment: Hi, I added a screendump through edits. I also managed to closer to the solution: `ROUNDDOWN(MAX(0,(MIN(term_end_date, student_end_date) - MAX(student_start_date, term_start_date)))/(365/12),0)`

Comment: Wouldn't Jim have studied in year 16/17 for `1` month and `12` months in 17/18?

Comment: @JvdV - updated the image - mistyped 2017 instead of 2018.

Comment: Do you have more examples. I think I do have an answer, but would like to test against your data a bit more

Comment: Sure, updated screenshot now.

Comment: Didn't Sponge Bob have 10 whole months attended in 17/18? That would be what my answer returns. Otherwise it becomes quite arbitrairy. What if he enrolled on 29/09/2017? Plus, with your logic he would have had 1 month of class in 2021/2022, no 0.

Comment: Yes, 10.78 months.

Comment: There's a financial calculation included (which I've excluded in the screenshot) that depends on whole months.

Comment: I understand whole months, but logicly would be `10` months for Sponge Bob in 17/18 (since he only spent 10 whole months in that study year). Otherwise, with you current logic you must also add a month to 21/22 for him instead of 0.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the screenshot. Essentially, I know that each student receives funding for university over the whole duration of the course. I am trying to match the total payments per each academic year and for totals of each academic year to equal the total course funding. The fractional months is creating a problem therein. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution which works a treat:

[image]

Thanks for all your help everyone.

Answer (score 0):

=DATEDIF(A1,B1,”M”) will give the number of whole months between 2 dates (i.e., excluding start and end months) where dates are entered in A1 and B1. The “M” signifies that you’d like the information reported in months.

For a *more* accurate result, try:
=(DATEDIF(A1,B1,”D”) / 365) * 12. If the dates span multiple years - including leap years - try dividing by 365.25 vs 365.

Comment: Hi, I've reviewed your answer and tried it previously - this isn't able to cross reference the academic/term years.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this UDF.

```
Function MonthsOverlap(Rng As Range, _
                       AccYear As Integer) As String
    ' 016

    Const Ststart As Long = 1               ' index of array 'Study'
    Const Stend As Long = 2                 ' index of array 'Study'

    Dim Fun As Integer                      ' Months of overlap
    Dim YearStart As Date, YearEnd As Date
    Dim Study As Variant

    YearStart = DateSerial(AccYear, 8, 1)   ' modify year and day as required
    YearEnd = DateAdd("yyyy", 1, YearStart)
    Study = Rng.Value                       ' Rng columns must be adjacent

    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        If Study(1, Ststart) <= YearStart Then
            Fun = DateDiff("m", .Max(Study(1, Ststart), YearStart), .Min(Study(1, Stend), YearEnd))
        ElseIf Study(1, Ststart) <= YearEnd Then
             Fun = DateDiff("m", .Max(Study(1, Ststart), YearStart), YearEnd)
        End If
        Fun = .Max(Fun, 0)
    End With

    MonthsOverlap = Fun & " month" & IIf(Fun = 1, "", "s")
End Function
```

I tested it in a sheet like the one pictured below. Please observe the formula in the Formula Bar.
[image]

As you see, the function returns unexpected results for the years 2017 and 2019. I don't think they are wrong. The formula just uses rounding of months different from your system. I think the function can be modified to accommodate your rule once you make it known. Meanwhile it follows Microsoft's rule which, frankly, I also don't know. However, observe that the total time of study is 24 months which is correct and therefore sufficient, in conjunction with a look at the clock, to convince me to let good be good enough for today :-)

Comment: Sorry, doesn't suffice :/ Thank you anyways.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't suffice: If you have a solution, publish it here as your own answer. If you don't have one, work with me on the rounding. In 2017 the student studied for 1 month and 7 days. You want this rounded to 1 month. My formula says he studied during two months. That result can be rounded but you would need to set the rules by which rounding is done. This information is missing from your question.

Comment: Hi Variatus - I published a solution below :)

Comment: @Mr Agent Smith Thank you. Your solution looks very nice but it doesn't tackle the task of rounding. Therefore it is likely that not all results it produces will be to your liking. Tests should include dates leaving less than half a month to round, more than half a month to round, requiring no rounding (attendance and academic year precisely aligned) and exactly half months, meaning 14, 15 and 16 days, depending upon the month, at both ends. That's why I didn't want to delve into the subject without a nod form you. But I do recommend that you test thoroughly before you rejoice. Good luck!